# showing div near save button if condition is true

Tags: php, html, css

I have simple code in php to enter name and address to the database.If name is already present in the database printing the message saying that it is already present ,if not entering data into database.But i want message has to be displayed near save button

```
  <form  method="POST" action=""  >
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><br>Name t</td><td><br><input type="text" name="Name" id="wgtmsr" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><br>Address</td>
        <td><br/><textarea rows="3" cols="33" name="Address" id="inc_address" required></textarea></td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><br></td><td><input type="submit" class="sav" name="rep" value="Save" id="btnsize" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['rep'])) 
     {
     $Name=$_POST['Name'];
     $Address=$_POST['Address'];

    try{
     $test=/* query check if name already present in database*/
    if(!$test)
    {
    /*then insert into database*/
    }else{

    ?> <div id="msg">
       <?php echo "alreday present";?>
       </div>
      <?php
          }
           }catch(Exception $e) {
               //echo "Error  ".$e->getMessage();

          }
    }
```

But div is coming above the table.Please give suggestions so how can i style it near the save button
style:

```
 #msg
  {
  color:#EA6262;
  font-size:14pt;
  margin-left:27% ; 
  margin-bttom:5% ; 

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert div after save button like

```
<input type="submit" class="sav" name="rep" value="Save" id="btnsize" /><span class="err" id="add_err"></span>
```

You can print the error using javascript.

```
document.getElementById("add_err").innerHTML = "Already having name!";
```

I tried similar thing its working

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: root
 * Date: 3/9/15
 * Time: 4:03 PM
 */
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <form>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" /><span class="adderr" name="adderr" id="adderr"></span>
   </form>

   <?php
   $var=0;
   if($var==0)
   {?>
       <script>

           document.getElementById("adderr").innerHTML = "Already having name!";
       </script>
   <?php
   }

   ?>

</body>

</html>
```

It works fine
[image: You can see the output]

Comment: you saying inside if condition <script>document.getElementById("add_err").innerHTML = "Already having name!";</script>

Comment: Yes Because script also called if the condition is true. You cam also format the error message like #add_err{color:red;align:center;}

Comment: tried but it is not giving any message.page will just refresh when i press save button

Comment: giving error as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: I tried similar thing its working`<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: root
 * Date: 3/9/15
 * Time: 4:03 PM
 */
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <form>

       <input type="submit" name="submit" /><span class="adderr" name="adderr" id="adderr"></span>
   </form>

   <?php
   $var=0;
   if($var==0)
   {?>
       <script>

           document.getElementById("adderr").innerHTML = "Already having name!";
       </script>
   <?php
   }

   ?>

</body>

</html>` It works fine

Comment: If possible share the code what are you doing actually